# Google Analytics Info on ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am wrting an ASP.NET Application.

I've already added javascript on master page that sends client visits to Google Analytics.

So I can view the statistics from Web interface of Google Analytics.

Now I need to show on the footer of Main Page the count of active (online) users and count of visits for today from Google Analytics.

Is there any advice? How can i achieve these goals?

Answer (score 2):

[Displaying Google Analytics Data in ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/119/Displaying-Google-Analytics-Data-in-ASP.NET) may be the good approach for your requirement !
And another link , [Google Analytics API integration with ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ravi_panara/google-analytics-api-integration-with-Asp-Net/) !